# How to know if NSManagedObjectContext with MagicalRecord is nil?

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using MagicalRecord in my app.

When a user logout, I do

```
[MagicalRecord cleanUp];
```

But some async operations are still receiving answer from my backend, so when my app receive that answer, it tries to add or to get info from my CoreData Model and it crash.

How can I check if `MagicalRecord - NSManagedObjectContext` is nil?

This is one point of my source code where I have to check it:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operationUserData = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

        [mixpanel.people set:[self createMixPanelData:JSON]];

        User *user = (User *)[User findFirst];

        user.isPremium = [JSON valueForKey:@"isPremium"];

        [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

        NSLog(@"error %@", [error description]);
    }];
```

When I do `User *user = (User *)[User findFirst];` it crash with the following error:

`Default context is nil! Did you forget to initialize the Core Data Stack?`

And this is the crashed line:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *defaultContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
```

I have created a NSOperationQueue in my AppDelegate to add operations. When I logout, I cancelAllOperations but the queue doesn't clean.

```
- (void)logOut:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"A- Operation count: %lu", (unsigned long)[appDelegate.queue operationCount]);
    [appDelegate.queue cancelAllOperations];
    NSLog(@"B- Operation count: %lu", (unsigned long)[appDelegate.queue operationCount]);
}
```

Output:

```
2015-10-29 14:51:42.251 MyApp[1389:689920] A- Operation count: 527
2015-10-29 14:51:42.256 MyApp[1389:689920] B- Operation count: 527
```

Comment: Hi. Which is a version of `MagicalRecord` you use? Maybe just cancel all operation when you perform cleanup?

Comment: I'm trying to cancel de operation with    `[AFAPIClient cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];` But it doesn't cancel anything. AFAPIClient is an instance of AFHTTPClient. I don't know the MagicalRecord version because this is a inherited project but files said 2012 as the year of the file

Comment: Can you show a implementation of method `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:`? In general case it is should be `[AFAPIClient.operationQueue cancelAllOperations] or [AFAPIClient cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:@"xx"]`. AFAPIClient has a direct access to the `operationQueue`.

Comment: `cancelPreviousPerformRequestWithTarget:` is from iOS 9.1 SDK, is not my own method. I have added NSLog to check what happend with `cancelAllOperations` but it cancel nothing. Check it in my edited question

Comment: If you want only check the context on nil you can just invoke `[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext]` to get him. `MagicalRecord` has the single static default context with type `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` (it is singleton in the your app), which you can get via category method `MR_defaultContext ` or `defaultContext` if you turn on suppressing the `MR_`-prefix.

Comment: When context is nil, it crash

Comment: Hi. Sorry for my english, maybe i don't understand your problem. See this gist [https://gist.github.com/Mozilla9/1514bf45c5c40ad31f55](https://gist.github.com/Mozilla9/1514bf45c5c40ad31f55). What is the problem make a checking on `nil` in the your success handler?

Comment: Because after calling `[MagicalRecord cleanUp]`, `[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext]` give me a Crash, I'm not sure why

Comment: I understood. You got a crash because inside the method `MR_defaultContext` exists `NSAssert` - `NSAssert(MagicalRecordDefaultContext != nil, @"Default context is nil! Did you forget to initialize the Core Data Stack?");`. You can turn off the assert in the `BuildSettings` of your project. 

The best way to invoking the `[MagicalRecord cleanUp]` is the method `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application`. Perhaps you should refactor `Logout`-part of the app.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will refactor my logout and also, test if I can turn off that assert ;)

Comment: But are there anyway to check whether default context is nil without turn off assert?